# Is there a possibility to fix parameters in the R package poLCA?

Tags: r, degrees-of-freedom, latent-class

I'm using the R package poLCA to compute a latent class analysis with 3 dichotomous variables. As I assume 4 classes, the degrees of freedom are negative.

```
  poLCA(formula=cbind(item1, item2, item3)~1, 
    data=mydata, 
    nclass= 4, 
    na.rm=FALSE, 
    graphs=TRUE
    )
```

Getting the Output:

```
Conditional item response (column) probabilities,
by outcome variable, for each class (row) 

$item1
           Pr(1)  Pr(2)
class 1:  0.2955 0.7045
class 2:  0.0000 1.0000
class 3:  0.0000 1.0000
class 4:  0.0000 1.0000

$item2
           Pr(1)  Pr(2)
class 1:  1.0000 0.0000
class 2:  0.8142 0.1858
class 3:  0.3262 0.6738
class 4:  0.7891 0.2109

$item3
           Pr(1)  Pr(2)
class 1:  0.9003 0.0997
class 2:  0.4602 0.5398
class 3:  0.0735 0.9265
class 4:  0.5550 0.4450

Estimated class population shares 
 0.1295 0.231 0.4318 0.2078 

Predicted class memberships (by modal posterior prob.) 
 0.0345 0.6626 0.3029 

========================================================= 
Fit for 4 latent classes: 
========================================================= 
number of observations: 8425 
number of fully observed cases: 7607 
number of estimated parameters: 15 
residual degrees of freedom: -8 
maximum log-likelihood: -10622.57 

AIC(4): 21275.15
BIC(4): 21380.73
G^2(4): 3.804972e-09 (Likelihood ratio/deviance statistic) 
X^2(4): 1.902663e-09 (Chi-square goodness of fit) 

ALERT: negative degrees of freedom; respecify model
```

However did I not find a possibility to fix parameters (i.e. item response probabilities within classes) or give them the same value in order to reduce the freely estimated parameters. Is there any possibility/ workaround for that? Could not find anything in the documantation.

Answer (score 1):

I emailed the author of the package, his answer was:

> Unfortunately, the current version of poLCA doesn't offer an option to
>   hold certain values fixed.

Hence I switched to **MPlus** that lets you fix parameters within each class:

```
DATA: file = "data.dat";

VARIABLE:
    names = item1
            item2
            item3
            item4
            item5;

    classes = class(4);

    categorical = item1
                  item2
                  item3
                  item4
                  item5;

    missing = all (-99);

ANALYSIS:
    TYPE = mixture;

    ITERATIONS = 20000;

    STARTS = 100 10;

MODEL:
  %class#1%        !fixing probabilities in class 1
    [item1$1@-5];  !for threshold=1 (dichotomous [0,1])
    [item2$1@-5];  !min = -15, max = 15
    [item3$1@-5];
    [item4$1@-5];
    [item5$1@-5];

  %class#2%        !fixing probabilities in class 2
    [item1$1@-2];
    [item2$1@-2];
    [item3$1@-2];
    [item4$1@-2];
    [item5$1@-2];

  %class#3%        !fixing probabilities in class 3
    [item1$1@2];
    [item2$1@2];
    [item3$1@2];
    [item4$1@2];
    [item5$1@2];

  %class#4%        !fixing probabilities in class 4
    [item1$1@5];
    [item2$1@5];
    [item3$1@5];
    [item4$1@5];
    [item5$1@5];
```

You could also label parameters and then introduce model constraints. Here an example for item 1:

```
MODEL:
  %class#1%
    [item1$1] (p11);  !labelling parameters

  %class#2%
    [item1$1] (p12);

  %class#3%
    [item1$1] (p13);

  %class#4%
    [item1$1] (p14);

MODEL CONSTRAINT:
  p11 = p12;
  p13 = p14;
```